# I got error code 1442 for creating TRIGGER in MySQL and another syntax error for my other trigger? How can I fix it?

Tags: mysql, triggers, mysql-workbench

I'm trying to create TRIGGERS in MySQL but I got a syntax error message. Here's my code for creating the tables and inserting the values:

The first table:

```
CREATE TABLE widgetSale (
id INTEGER auto_increment,
item_id INT,
customer_id INT,
quan INT,
price INT,
reconciled INT,
primary key (id));

INSERT INTO widgetSale (item_id, customer_id, quan, price, reconciled) VALUES (1, 3, 5, 1995, 0);
INSERT INTO widgetSale (item_id, customer_id, quan, price, reconciled) VALUES (2, 2, 3, 1495, 1);
INSERT INTO widgetSale (item_id, customer_id, quan, price, reconciled) VALUES (3, 1, 1, 2995, 0);
SELECT * FROM widgetSale;
```

My first trigger for the first table:

```
delimiter //
CREATE TRIGGER updateWidgetSale BEFORE UPDATE ON widgetSale for each row
BEGIN
IF NEW.reconciled = 1 THEN
SIGNAL SQLSTATE VALUE '45000'
  SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'cannot update table "widgetSale" after it has been reconciled';
END IF;
END
//
```

And here are my tables to create trigger for timestamps:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS widgetSale;
CREATE TABLE widgetCustomer(
id integer auto_increment,
name TEXT,
last_order_id INT,
stamp TEXT,
primary key(id) );

CREATE TABLE widgetSale (
id integer auto_increment,
item_id INT, 
customer_id INTEGER,
quan INT, 
price INT, 
stamp TEXT,
primary key(id) );

CREATE TABLE widgetLog (
id integer auto_increment,
stamp TEXT, 
event TEXT, 
username TEXT, 
tablename TEXT, 
table_id INT,
primary key(id));

INSERT INTO widgetCustomer (name) VALUES ('Bob');
INSERT INTO widgetCustomer (name) VALUES ('Sally');
INSERT INTO widgetCustomer (name) VALUES ('Fred');
SELECT * FROM widgetCustomer;

delimiter //
CREATE TRIGGER stampSale before insert on widgetSale for each row 
BEGIN
SET NEW.stamp = CURDATE();
update widgetCustomer set last_order_id = new.item_id where widgetCustomer.id = new.customer_id;
update widgetCustomer set stamp = new.stamp;
INSERT INTO widgetLog (stamp, event, username, tablename, table_id) VALUES (NEW.stamp, 'INSERT ', 'TRIGGER', 'widgetSale', NEW.customer_id);
END
//

INSERT INTO widgetSale (item_id, customer_id, quan, price) VALUES (1, 3, 5, 1995);
INSERT INTO widgetSale (item_id, customer_id, quan, price) VALUES (2, 2, 3, 1495);
INSERT INTO widgetSale (item_id, customer_id, quan, price) VALUES (3, 1, 1, 2995);

SELECT * FROM widgetSale;
SELECT * FROM widgetCustomer;
SELECT * FROM widgetLog;
```

So my problem is:

1. I could not create the first trigger because it seems the raise function does not exist in MySQL. I was advised to use Signal statement but I don't know what syntax should I put?
2. I was able to create the trigger for timestamps but I got error code 1442. I don't know what went wrong with my syntax?

*Updated: I was able to solve my problems now, for the second trigger, turns out I need to CREATE TRIGGER BEFORE INSERT, not AFTER INSERT (because otherwise I cannot update the table), and wrote two UPDATE statements to update the widgetCustomer table in which I want to update the id and the stamp column, and I have to do that by writing two separate UPDATE statements.

Comment: I guess you aren't setting the `DELIMITER` in the mysql client. You should read https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/stored-programs-defining.html

Comment: *SELECT **RAISE** (ROLLBACK, 'cannot update table "widgetSale"') FROM widgetSale* - no such function in MySQL, use SIGNAL statement.

Comment: By the way, you specified an unknown column name `reconciled` in your last three insert statements starting from `INSERT INTO widgetSale (item_id, customer_id, quan, price, reconciled) VALUES (1, 3, 5, 1995, 0);`

Comment: @BillKarwin thanks for your help, I was able to create the triggers now but I got error code 1442 for my last trigger which is a trigger for timestamps. I'm not sure how to fix it?

Comment: @Akina I could not figure out the correct syntax for my case, I read the documentation but it only shows the signal statement where there is IF ELSE statement. How can I adjust the syntax for my case?

Comment: @blabla_bingo thanks for catching that, I just updated my post now.

Comment: I cannot understand the logic of this trigger. Do you want to forbid any changes in the row in `widgetSale` if `reconciled = 1` in this row? if so then  use IF EXISTS. Without such checking you'll forbid all changes for this table. And you must check not `reconciled` but `NEW.reconciled` or `OLD.reconciled` or both, depends on needed logic.

Comment: Thanks @BillKarwin, I was able to solve my problems, for the timestamp trigger, turns out I need to make a TRIGGER BEFORE INSERT, not AFTER INSERT, and I wrote two UPDATES statements to update the widgetCustomer table. I already updated my post to include my modified codes, thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Summary of errors from above comment thread:

You need to use `DELIMITER` when defining stored routines in the MySQL client. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/stored-programs-defining.html

Use the `SIGNAL` statement to raise errors in a MySQL stored routine. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/signal.html
Your condition appears to be `reconciled = 1`, and you reference that column in the row that spawned the trigger as `NEW.reconciled`. You don't need to SELECT from the table to get that column.

```
delimiter //
CREATE TRIGGER updateWidgetSale BEFORE UPDATE ON widgetSale
BEGIN
  IF NEW.reconciled = 1 THEN
    SIGNAL SQLSTATE VALUE '45000'
      SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'cannot update table "widgetSale" after it has been reconciled';
  END IF;
END
//
```

User blabla_bingo noticed you had mistakenly referenced `reconciled` in some INSERT statements where it didn't belong. I guess it was the result of copy & paste of some lines of code.

Re error 1442: MySQL does not allow you to INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE the same table for which the trigger was spawned. In other words, if the trigger is for an operation `ON widgetSale`, then you can't `UPDATE widgetSale` in that trigger.

But you don't need to UPDATE the table to change one column in current row for which the trigger spawned. You simply reference the columns of current row with `NEW.columnName` like the following to set one column to a scalar value:

```
SET NEW.stamp = CURDATE();
```

`CURDATE()` is an equivalent way of writing `DATE(NOW())`.